# show article first image from database as cover image

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-5

i have the `images` field in Articles table and i will save all images into this field as array : `images/image1.jpg,images/image2.jpg, ...`

in my index page, i am getting all articles and show them in home page :

```
$articles = \App\Article::all();
```

i want to just load first image from every article as cover image and show that but the images field is string. what can i do?

```
       @foreach($articles as $article)
        <div class="article_wrapper">
            <div class="article_body">
                    @foreach($article->images as $image)
                        {{ $image }}
                    @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
      @endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a route only:

```
Route::any('/article/images/{id}', ['as' => 'article.image', function($id) {

    $article = Article::find($id);

    $images = explode(',',$article->images);

    return Response::download($images[0]);
}]);
```

Using a controller:

```
namespace MyNamespace;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use App\Article;
use Response;

class ImagesController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $article = Article::find($id);

        $images = explode(',',$article->images);

        return Response::download($images[0]);
    }
}
```

Your route:

```
Route::get('/article/images/{id}', ['as' => 'article.image', 'uses' => 'MyNamespace\ImagesController@show']);
```

Then in your view:

```
<img src="{{route('article.image', ['id' => $article->getKey()])}}" />
```

So that your view will look like:

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
    <div class="article_wrapper">
        <div class="article_body">
            <img src="{{route('article.image', ['id' => $article->getKey()])}}" />
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

If you aren't saving the fullpath in the images field then prefix it:

```
return Response::download('C:\downloadpath\' . $images[0]);
```